# Сборка приложения с QT в Linux без зависимости от динамических библиотек

Tags: linux, qt, static

Мне нужно собрать приложение с QT, без зависимости от любых библиотек. Я скачал qt исходники и собрал их ститически(с опцией configure -static) и установил в /opt/Qt5.8static/. Я проверил, что все файлы в /opt/Qt5.8static/lib не имею зависимости от каких-то библиотек.

Я создал тестовый проект

.pro файл:

```
CONFIG += debug console
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -L/opt/Qt5.8static/lib
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Выполнил

```
qmake
make
```

Выдаются ошибки:

```
g++ -static -o main main.o   -L/opt/Qt5.8static/lib -lQt5Gui -L/usr/lib
-lpng16 -lharfbuzz -lQt5Core -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lm -ldl -lrt -lz 
-lpcre16 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lGL -lpthread 
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng16
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licui18n
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licuuc
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -licudata
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre16
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

Я открыл Makefile в нем в переменной LIBS указаны ссылки на несколько библиотек(glib-2.0, gthread-2.0, pcre16, icuuc и др.). Я удалил эти ссылки, и снова запустил make. Все нормально собралось, файл работает правильно и не имеет ссылок на библиотеки.

Как мне удалить ссылки на вышеозначенные библиотеки из Makefile?

Comment: я думаю, имеет смысл уточнить, что вам требуется. насколько я понял, ваш вопрос в том, как изменить файл с суффиксом `.pro` так, чтобы генерируемый программой *qmake* файл не содержал упоминаний динамических библиотек в переменной `LIBS`.

Comment: возможно, поможет добавление `static` в [переменную `CONFIG`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config).

Comment: Когда линкуете статически должны быть `libpng16.a` и подобное вместо `-lpng16`.